# How to load forked github repo as gem in sinatra/rack application

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundler, rack

I'm trying to use a gem called "rbing" but there is an issue with it and the project has been abandoned but someone made a fix in a repo so I decided to use bundler to specify the new version.

```
gem "rbing", :git => "https://github.com/KellyMahan/rbing.git"
```

It even installed correctly when I ran bundle install, but inside my Gemfile RubyMine is complaining that "The gem with the specified version requirements isn't available inside SDK RVM: ruby-2.0.0"

And it doesn't show up in my external libraries directory.

Any help is very much appreciated guys,

Cheers, Adam

EDIT: Ruby version,

```
Bundler 1.3.5
Ruby 2.0.0 (2013-05-14 patchlevel 195) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
Rubygems 2.0.3
rvm 1.20.11 (stable)
GEM_HOME /Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
GEM_PATH /Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195:/Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-        p195@global
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
```

Comment: When you run `bundle install` are you sure that you're running with the same version of Ruby that RubyMine is using? Are you running `bundle install` from the command line or from the RubyMine Tools menu?

Comment: I'm running it from my own terminal. I cannot say that it's the same version RubyMine is using. Any ideas what to try?

Comment: Now for some reason my Gemfile and locked gemfile are reading that they are using the version from the correct git repository, yet when I go into the external library files for the gem, it is clearly the wrong version.

Comment: Try running `head -n 1 $(which bundle)` to see which Ruby it's using.

Comment: `bundle env` will also tell you the Ruby version.

Comment: That just pinged back a copy of my gemfile.lock

Comment: Look at the top of the output... there should also be version info for Bundler itself, Ruby, and Rubygems.

Comment: Ok, I updated my original question with the version and other info

Comment: It looks like Bundler is working correctly, so the problem might be on the RubyMine side. What happens when you run Bundler - Install from the RubyMine Tools menu?

Comment: Friend helped me fix it, the new code was on a different branch than what was accessible in the reference to the git repo

Answer (score 1):

Change your Gemfile to:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'rbing', :git => 'https://github.com/KellyMahan/rbing'
```

I just did it here for RubyMine 5.4 and it works like a charm:

[image]

Comment: Ah that's probably the better source regardless but it still isn't identifying the gem. For some reason it's unavailable in my SDK RVM: ruby-2.0.0 that you can probably see for yourself if you go to File > Default Settings in Ruby SDK and Gems in Rubymine.