# Bundler using wrong gem when specifying a forked version from github

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, bundler, rubymine

I've been having some serious pains getting rubymine to use a gem version specified by my bundler.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "sinatra"
gem "slim"
gem "dm-core"
gem "dm-migrations"
gem "rbing", :git => "https://github.com/KellyMahan/rbing.git"
```

When I run bundle install, it seems to download correctly.

```
Using rbing (1.1.0) from https://github.com/KellyMahan/rbing.git (at master) Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:
```

Yet every time, low and behold, I am to discover the gem currently being used as listed in my "External Libraries" directory in RubyMine, it is using the old version of the gem, and not the forked version from github.

Ideas? Any help is very much appreciated.

-Adam

EDIT:

Also, could it be possible there could be any issues with the rvm I'm using to use 2.0.0 that RubyMine is using as my default gem location. Could the forked version be downloaded to somewhere other than this rvm path that my RubyMine uses by default?

EDIT again:

I updated the unregisted git root that was rbing, and after I even successfully made the commit and changes were made.....it didn't affect the version of rbing sitting in my external library directory. Any help to figure this out will be unbelievably appreciated, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/19129880/29470 ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using `gem uninstall` to uninstall the old version?

If you don't know how, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902488/uninstall-old-ruby-gems-versions)

Comment: How can I tell which is the version of the original gem vs. the forked gem version? I can't seem to find a differentiating version id in https://github.com/KellyMahan/rbing/tree/azure other than the v1.1.0 version specified in the old version I don't want to use.

Comment: gem uninstall rbing --version 1.1.0 will uninstall the old gem. You could run bundle install after, just to check the git version is still installed

Comment: It does successfully but it still uses and lists the old version in my External Libraries directory in rubymine. At this point im almost positive it has something to do with which sdk it's using with my rvm.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* the case that git gems are installed by bundler in a different location than the normal gem path, but RubyMine has bundler integration and should be able to find the gem normally. Try running Bundler - Install from inside RubyMine and see what happens. It might be using a different Ruby version or there could be some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have been a bug in RubyMine 5.x that was fixed in version 6.0 related to the "External Libraries".  Please see this issue:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14584

Upgrading to version 6.0 RC seems to fix it.